# Show email reminder if receiver didn't respond for certain time

Tags: c#

I have one task such that make leave request form using c# in windows application. The steps are as follows.

1. After filling all the fields, mail should send to the manager.
2. If manager didn't see that email or he didn't give any response for one day, then we have to show a reminder or notification such that "waiting for response" (for example).

For the first step I know how to send an email through SMTP. But how to know that manager responds or not for that thread and showing notification (it may be alert message or windows notification). For all these process should I use work flows? 
Any best ways to do it?

Is it better to implement in asp.net or windows application. I am planning to do it windows application.

Answer (score 0):

*If the manager didn't see the email* can be accomplished by requesting a read receipt and checking for that. It's not foolproof, as the manager can simply decline to return the receipt, but it's the best you have.

*He didn't give a response for one day* is much harder though. The only way I can see to do this is funnel all communication back through your application as a man-in-the-middle. What I mean is to set the reply-to address to something your application has access to, then once your application reads it and records the response, the program forwards the email to the intended recipient. This way you can watch the response go by and forward it on to the intended recipient. This does mean you need your application to be running all the time, probably as a service.

The only other option is to forgo email altogether and use your application to read and respond to the requests. This way you have access to everything and can just keep a timestamp in your database.

Comment: oh..i think it may be little bit hard then. Need to do some R & D... Do you know any links to refer the above concepts..

Comment: No I don't but I think Google is your friend here. The problem is email inherently uses very simple protocols so there's no built-in way to "monitor" what happens with them, rather akin to snail mail. You can send a letter certified so you know someone gets it, but the only way to know if they reply is to wait for the reply to come.

Comment: I added another sentence to see if that helps explain what I mean. The first part is called a "read receipt" or "return receipt". The second and third parts don't really require searching so much as implementing IMHO (unless you need to read up on fetching email via `POP3` or `IMAP`, that is)